# When performing nearest neighbour matching in R, is it possible to view the identity of which cases matched with which controls?

Tags: r, nearest-neighbor, propensity-score-matching

I'm first trying this out in R Studio with a small practice dataset found here (584 obs, 5 variables) (https://scholarworks.umass.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1330&context=pare)

Using this code I can use nearest neighbor matching to find the mean difference in matched cases and controls (1:1) where stw is my grouping variable and tot, min, and dis are the matching variables:

```
m.out = matchit(stw ~ tot + min + dis,
                data = mydata, method = "nearest",
                ratio = 1)
```

what I want to know is how can I view which cases have matched with which controls (i.e. shows me the exact identity)?

I would also like to do this where I match 5 nearest neighbors (i.e. ratio = 5) and also view those exact identities. is there additional code needed for this?

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity of units within a match are stored in the `match.matrix` component of the `matchit` output object. This is a matrix with as many rows as there are treated units and with `ratio` columns. Each row corresponds to a treated unit, and the values in the row correspond to the identity of the control unit matched to that treated unit. Below is an example:

```
> head(m$match.matrix)
     1         2        
NSW1 "PSID305" "PSID369"
NSW2 "PSID198" "PSID273"
NSW3 "PSID333" "PSID282"
NSW4 "PSID400" "PSID92" 
NSW5 "PSID426" "PSID262"
NSW6 "PSID391" "PSID261"
```

Treated unit `NSW1` is matched with control units `PSID305` and `PSID369`. If the original dataset did not have row names, the values correspond to the row of the dataset where the corresponding unit appears.