# R Coarsened Exact Matching (Printing out matched pairs)

Tags: r, package, propensity-score-matching

I am trying to implement a one to one coarsened exact matching. I am following the help package available here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cem/cem.pdf

For now, I am trying to implement the example on pg 3 on the lalonde dataset from the package Matching. My code is as follows:

```
library(cem)
library(Matching)

data(lalonde)
mat <- cem(treatment="treat",data=lalonde, drop="re78",k2k=TRUE,method = "euclidean", keep.all=FALSE)
#variable name "treat" is different from cran documentation
print(mat)

> print(mat)
             G0  G1
  All       260 185
  Matched    87  87
  Unmatched 173  98
```

This seems to work perfectly. Using "print(mat)" prints out the number of matches and the "mat" objects seems to have multiple objects in it except for the information for the matched pairs. This seems to be a trivial problem but I could not figure out the information for the matched pairs from the documentation.

Could someone point out how to obtain the pairwise observations which were matched? For eg. Obs 1 - Obs 100 etc. I am looking to get the pairs which were matched together.

The closest object that I can see is:

```
mat[["matched"]]
```

However this does not tell me which observation in the treatment group was matched with an observation in the control group (and the observation ID).

I know I am missing something simple here. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done with `cem`. It doesn't actually create matched pairs; within each stratum defined by the coarsened covariates, it ensures the number of treated and control units within each stratum is the same. The strata can be exported and you can attempt to find which units belong to which strata.

The implementation of coarsened exact matching in the `MatchIt` package does have this capability. Below is how you would perform the matching using `MatchIt`:

```
library(MatchIt)
data("lalonde", package = "MatchIt") #note, different from lalonde in Matching

m.out <- matchit(treat ~ age + educ + race + married + nodegree + re74 + re75,
                 data = lalonde, method = "cem", k2k = TRUE, 
                 k2k.method = "euclidean")
```

The identity of the matched pairs is stored in the `match.matrix` attribute of the `m.out` output object (i.e., `m.out$match.matrix`). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64026870/when-performing-nearest-neighbour-matching-in-r-is-it-possible-to-view-the-iden) for example. Each row corresponds to a treated unit and the entries in the column correspond to the matched control units. To create a dataset containing only the matched units, you can then run `match.data()` on `m.out`. The `subclass` column in the output contains pair membership. See the `MatchIt` [vignette on estimating effects after matching](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchIt/vignettes/estimating-effects.html) for information on how to estimate effects while accounting for pair membership. The section "After Pair Matching Without Replacement" is appropriate for coarsened exact matching with `k2k = TRUE`.

Note that how coarsened exact matching is implemented in `MatchIt` is slightly different to how it is in `cem`. The [help page](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/reference/method_cem.html) for coarsened exact matching with `MatchIt` explains these differences, so don't be alarmed if the results differ between the two packages. I am the maintainer of `MatchIt` and wrote its documentation so let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really appreciate your help.